# Set default Ant targets with source control

Tags: git, ant

I'm looking for ways to set default Ant targets with source control (git) so that when creating a new workspace the targets are set and don't have to be manually checked. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I haven't used ant in years, but can't you just specify the default target in the `project` element? Why do you need source control involved?

Comment: @jingx I needed a way to set default targets without having to go through multiple project build files and doing Run as... then clicking targets. I ended up just chaining the targets with depends="foo" in xml build files. This allowed the default target to depend on the non-defaulted targets and thus call them before it could be executed.